# Cannot create phantom Applicative functor class

Tags: haskell, applicative

I am trying to implement phantom Applicative functor from Monoid, described in section 4 in paper [Applicative programming with effects](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/%7Eross/papers/Applicative.html):

```
newtype Accy o a = Acc {acc :: o}

instance Monoid o => Applicative (Accy o) where
    pure _              = Acc mempty
    Acc o1 <*> Acc o2   = Acc (o1 `mappend` o2)
```

However, I get following error:

```
    * Could not deduce (Functor (Accy o))
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: Monoid o
        bound by the instance declaration
        at phantom-applicative-functor.hs:7:10-41
    * In the instance declaration for `Applicative (Accy o)'
  |
7 | instance Monoid o => Applicative (Accy o) where
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have tried adding language extension such as:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
```

But, it didn't help. Is it possible to implement the phantom applicative function as described in the paper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, in addition to the `Applicative` instance you must give a `Functor` instance. You can write it yourself:

```
instance Functor (Accy o) where fmap _ (Acc o) = Acc o
```

or ask GHC to write it for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
newtype Accy o a = Acc {acc :: o} deriving Functor
```

Comment: Thank you! It can compile and load the code now.